# How to store my encryption key in secure way while doing client side encryption in mobile app?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, encryption, cryptography

I want to do client side encryption in mobile app and the encrypted data will be saved in server. The data should be decrypt when user logged in another device also.
Is there any other way to store the "key" securely, which is used for encrypt and decrypt my data other than my server?  Usually we store encryption "key" in server, but i need more secure place than my server?

Can we use solutions like AWS KMS for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could just never store the (presumably symmetric) key on the device, but instead deterministically regenerate the key each session using a  [Password-Based Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)